# Asp.net Response Status 0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i'm trying to use xmlhttpRequest to send a value to the server and get a response. But my response status returned is 0(zero).

Take a look on my client side code:

```
//The button click will call "acessoPortal()"
function acessarPortal() {
    var ulogin = "login=" + login();
    var usenha = "senha=" + senha();
    var udominio = "dominio=" + dominio();

    var url = "http://localhost:35040/default.aspx?dominio=" + dominio() + "&login=" + login() + "&senha=" + senha();
    abrirPag(url);
}

function abrirPag(url) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = verificadorDeEstado;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
        alert("");
    }
    return url;
}

// Verifica o estado do objeto
function verificadorDeEstado(div_id) {
    alert('verificador de estados' + xmlhttp.readyState);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Completo
        alert('Requisição completada: '+ xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Resposta do Servidor: OK
            var local = div_id;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Problema: " + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

I can send data to my server but i can not read the response.
take a look on my server side code:

```
[PageLoadEvent]
var b = Request.QueryString["teste"];//receive the querys
Response.Write("sucesso:("+b+")");//write the response
Response.End();//end;
```

-- EDIT --
button action:

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Acessar', type: 'success', width: '80%', onClick: acessarPortal }">
        </div>
```

Comment: You are not canceling the button click. How is the function  above being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the action that calls the function.

You do not show how you call it so it is either

```
 function acessarPortal (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ...
```

or

```
onclick="return acessarPortal();"
```

and

```
function acessarPortal () {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message status=0 occurs when I access XMLHttpRequest on local domain.